# How to use external html file to send data in mailgun?

Tags: html, node.js, email, mailgun

I use mail-gun to send mails. But instead of just adding html tags in html field I want to create a separate html file and add it there. How to do it? (I use Node.js express framework)

```
 var data = {
      from: 'EasyFoods <postmaster@sandboxbd57df4272094073a1546c209403a45b.mailgun.org>',
      to: req.user.email,
      subject: 'Order is placed',
      html: '<h1>You just placed an order!</h1>'
    };
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can do this.Read HTML file using `fs` and store in a variable, Now pass this variable email data

Try below code.

```
var fs = require('fs');
var mailGun = require("mailgun-js")({
    apiKey: "API-KEY",
    domain:"DOMAIN-NAME"
});
var emailBody = fs.readFileSync('your html file path').toString();
var emailData = {
    from: "fromEmail",
    to: "toEmail",
    subject: "subject",
    html: emailBody
}
mailGun.messages().send(emailData, function (error, body) {
    if(!error){
        console.log("sendEmail : email Sent to : "+email);
    }else{
        console.log("sendEmail : Can not send email to : "+email+" : Error : "+error);
    }
});
```

This solution works for me.